# Which Laravel version should I start using?

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I plan to familiarize with Laravel framework, but I don't know which version to use 4 or 5.

I assume that many companies are working on older versions for their projects and it will take some time to migrate to the newest ones (if ever). The 5.X version is very recent and probably not that common, should I start learning the 4.X version ?

Also are there many differences between 4.X and 5.X versions ?

Comment: Don't learn for companies.. learn for yourself.. it is better to know and use the latest technologies as they are coming with many improvements and new features.. if you're a good programmer with knowledge about many frameworks the companies would hire you not because you know a certain framework but because you have the capability to use any framework..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite an opinion based question; by which I mean the answers you get are going to primarily be based on that persons opinion rather than fact.

Put it this way, would you build an application on outdated technology? No. Then why code one in outdated technology?

L5.1 and 5.2 are fairly similar and the most recent releases of Laravel, I would start with them to ensure you get access to on-going updates and support.

There are also a number of differences between L4 and L5, L4 apps being upgraded to L5 require a number of changes to be compatible - furthermore many packages developed for Laravel are now only done or continue to be updated for L5.

Comment: Thanks for clarification !

Answer (score 2):

If I would be You, I would start learning from L5.2 (master) version, since only L5.1 is LTS and not much changed in code.

About differences: Yes, that are different, for myself, to adapt from L4 to L5 it took some time.